# MVC cast in editorfor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How can I correctly bind to the model if I am casting inside the an editor template ? What would the name of the input look like ?

So I have a bit of a complex `Model`, where one of the properties is a class e.g. `Shape` which is extended by other classes, e.g. `Square` and `Circle`.
Therefore I have trouble when trying to bind to the `Shape` property of the `Model`:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => (m.Shape as Square).Something, "Yes")
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => (m.Shape as Square).Something, "No")
```

in the `POST` request the `Shape` property shows up as `null` in the model.

can someone please nudge me in the right direction? what is the formcollection key for the inputs supposed to look like ???

Comment: You cannot bind a radio button (or any html form control) to a complex object (`Shape` or `Square`). You need to bind to a property of `Shape` or `Square` (e.g. `string`). What is it your actually trying to do?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I'm binding to a property of that object.

Comment: Then what is the purpose of the cast? It makes no sense (html has no concept of what type of class your using - all you can generate is `<input type="radio" name="Something" value="Yes" />`).

Comment: @StephenMuecke because the Square would have properties than the Shape doesnt...

Comment: And how do you think it would bind to anything when you post back (your model has as property which is typeof `Shape` so posting back properties of `Square` will be ignored by the `ModelBinder`!) You need to us a view model representing what you want to display/edit.

Answer (score 2):

The way MVC works with these lambda expressions is kind of weird, it never actually runs or uses in any way the lambda function as is. Instead it breaks it down to expression components and picks the parameter name (and `MethodInfo` for getters/setters etc) to use for data binding.

Unfortunately, your complex expression breaks their algorithm. That's fine, it's meant to be fast, not extremely flexible.

As to a fix, what I'd do is just add a `Square` property (`public Square SquareAccessor => Shape as Square;`) and bind to that. I'm assuming here you're assuming the cast is valid if you reach that branch, if not throw some `null` checks.

Comment: sorry, you mean add a separate Square property to the model ?

Comment: Yeah, exactly. Just to make the binding expression match the expected format.

Comment: is that the only way then? No workaround that I can integrate to still be able to do the casting ?

Answer (score 2):

the only workaround I found on that is cast that into view variable which name is exactly what you need to be in 'name' attribute

```
@{
  var Shape = Model.Shape as Square;
}
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => Shape.Something, "Yes")
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => Shape.Something, "No")
```

This way html will be rendered correctly, but still this is workaround - not a clean solution

Comment: Works like a charm, very silly that we have to do this lol, pretty sure the only other way would be overriding the default model binder, that would be a lotta work for something so simple..., well, that shows how dated asp.net mvc is